# RewriteRule for FASTCGI

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /WebInt/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

My shared hosting's SERVER API is CGI_FASTCGI and I got the "No input file specified." error on a blank page. I changed the htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /WebInt/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Now it is working  but this time i cannot use any GET variable. 
What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

The ? removes the original query string from the rewritten URL, which is the source of the "GET variables" in PHP.  You need to go back to the drawing board for why adding it allegedly resolved some problem of missing scripts being fed to the FCGI daemon.